# Ubuntu 10.10 / Debian preseed keyboard origin seed

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, preseed

Using a preseed file for Ubuntu 10.10 alternate, I am unable to skip pass the "Origin of keyboard" question. Any ideas why? My preseed file is as below
Reference link [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10442851)

```
#### Contents of the preconfiguration file (for squeeze)
### Localization
# Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US

# The values can also be preseeded individually for greater flexibility.
#d-i debian-installer/language string en
#d-i debian-installer/country string NL
#d-i debian-installer/locale string en_GB.UTF-8
# Optionally specify additional locales to be generated.
#d-i localechooser/supported-locales en_US.UTF-8, nl_NL.UTF-8

# Keyboard selection.
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i console-setup/modelcode string skip-config
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string us
# To select a variant of the selected layout (if you leave this out, the
# basic form of the layout will be used):
#d-i console-setup/variantcode string dvorak
```

Comment: I ran into this problem as well a couple years ago and never found a solution. http://www.ale.org/pipermail/ale/2008-March/101004.html

Comment: It seems we were not the only ones, definitely needs a ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just adding in a comment here, hope it helps a little bit...

I managed to get past this same issue by putting my settings in the boot default file for my pxe launch, as following:
vi pxelinux.cfg/default:

default install

label install

```
    menu label ^Install

    menu default

    kernel ubuntu-installer/i386/linux

    append ramdisk_size=14984 locale=en_US console-setup/ask_detect=false  console-setup/layoutcode=us  netcfg/choose_interface=eth1 netcfg/get_hostname=testserver url=http://10.255.0.1/ubuntu-preseeds/preseed.cfg vga=normal initrd=ubuntu-installer/i386/initrd.gz -- quiet
```

I hope that helps a little bit, sorry about the mess :)

Cheers,
Karl Kloppenborg.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: Hi Vener, I ended up working it out, I have posted a version of it on my company blog, have a look and give it a try :)

Comment: http://www.crucial.com.au/blog/

Comment: I take back what I said, I appears there was an error in the build script when I tried out this method, the VM ended up using an old .cfg It works. Thanks

Comment: No problem ;) Hopefully everything would be working nicely by now!

Answer (score 0):

from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/89185/what-is-the-correct-way-of-setting-up-an-abnt2-keyboard-layout-in-preseed/258570#258570

AFAIK you need all of

```
d-i     keyboard-configuration/variant select English (US)
d-i     console-keymaps-at/keymap select us
d-i     keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us
```

and possibly

```
console-setup/ask_detect=false console-setup/layoutcode=us keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap=us
```

on your append line of txt.cfg (or whatever isolinux config)